# Lumen Class Route Not found

Tags: laravel, lumen, laravel-passport

I am trying to implement the code stated in [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/api-authentication-with-passport).

```
$proxy = Request::create(
        '/oauth/token',
        'POST'
    );

    return Route::dispatch($proxy);
```

This gives me error **Class Route Not found**.My question is how can we use Route:dispatch() in lumen ?
Thanks

Comment: Lumen uses an entirely different router, this one: https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute

Comment: So by using fastRoute I may be solve above problem right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem.We can use the following code.

```
$proxy = Request::create(
        '/oauth/token',
        'post',
        [
            'grant_type'=>$grant_type,
            'client_id'=>$client_id,
            'client_secret'=>$client_secret,
            'username'=>$username,
            'password'=>$password
        ]

    );



    return App::dispatch($proxy);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Lumen 5.4
>
> ```
> global $app;    
>
> $proxy = Request::create(
>     '/oauth/token',
>     'post',
>     [
>         'grant_type'=>$grant_type,
>         'client_id'=>$client_id,
>         'client_secret'=>$client_secret,
>         'username'=>$username,
>         'password'=>$password
>     ]
>
> );
>
> return $app->dispatch($proxy);
> ```

Comment: How to add new headers in above ? any ideas